# Waiting for multiple deferred objects to be finished and use the resolved values

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out a way to wait for multiple deferred objects and process them once done, may be like to start next set for deferred objects.

I am stuck because the result of the following is not the it is expected to be.
I am expecting the result as

```
allDone resovled values are 1,2,3
```

The actual result is

```
allDone resovled values are 1,2
```

```js
var dfd1 = new $.Deferred();
var dfd2 = new $.Deferred();
var dfd3 = new $.Deferred(); 
var dfds = [ dfd1, dfd2, dfd3 ]; 
var resolvedValues = [];

$.when.apply($, dfds).done(function() {     
    dfds.forEach(function(dfd){
        console.log("inloop");      
        dfd.promise().done(function(value) {
            resolvedValues.push(value);         
        });     
    });
    console.log("allDone resovled values are" + resolvedValues);
})

dfd1.resolve(1);
dfd2.resolve(2);
dfd3.resolve(3);
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly, it was unreadable before. Have a clear and easy to read example will mean you're more likely to get quick and accurate answers.

Comment: Sorry I was above to do that, I have not posted questions here before.

Comment: No problem. I've edited the layout for you.

Comment: The thing is you are outputing log in console before the last one item in array is pushed

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because of event queue i guess: https://jsfiddle.net/d4nxmdLx/

Comment: Actually that is what I do not understand.

Comment: @A.Wolff: Huh, my understanding is that jQuery's Deferred called `done` callbacks *synchronously* when it was already resolved (which is one of the problems with Deferred vs. real promises). I can't see why in the code above why two of them would be sync and the third async. Bizarre.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, strange result: https://jsfiddle.net/d4nxmdLx/1/  ?!  In fact not that strange because we resolve dfd3 in last, so my example is not relevant

Comment: @A.Wolff: I figured out why. It's jQuery's broken sync/async thing again.

Comment: @user3397062: It's not okay to markedly change the question once it has answers; I've rolled back that edit. If after trying to apply this answer to your ajax situation you still have trouble, post a new question asking about the specific trouble you run into applying this.

Comment: ok sure thing, I will try to post another question.
Thanks

Comment: @user3397062: Well, try to apply the answer below first, though. It should be sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

For the *why*, see below. But you're overcomplicating it. :-) The callback you give the final promise you get from `when` gives you the resolved values as arguments:

```
$.when.apply($, dfds).done(function(a, b, c) {
    // Here, a is 1, b is 2, c is 3
    // Or you can access them on `arguments`
})
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var dfd1 = new $.Deferred();
var dfd2 = new $.Deferred();
var dfd3 = new $.Deferred(); 
var dfds = [ dfd1, dfd2, dfd3 ]; 
var resolvedValues = [];

$.when.apply($, dfds).done(function() {
    // Use a trick to turn `arguments` into a real array
    var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // Show what we got
    console.log("allDone: " + a.join(", "));
})

dfd1.resolve(1);
dfd2.resolve(2);
dfd3.resolve(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: I assume you're dealing with an array on purpose. If you have a fixed number of promises you need to wait on, just use the simpler form

```
$.when(dfd1, dfd2, dfd3).then(function(a, b, c) {
    // ...
});
```

---

Here's *why* you're getting the very odd result you're getting: jQuery's `Deferred`/`Promise` objects have a problem in that they are *chaotic*: When you call `done` on them, you don't know whether your callback will be executed *synchronously* or *asynchronously*. This is a serious flaw, and one that a true Promises/A+ implementation does not have (the callback is always asynchronous).

jQuery will call the callback *asynchronously* if the promise is not yet resolved. But it will call it *synchronously* if it *isn't* resolved:

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
d1.done(function() {
    console.log("I'm called asynchronously");
});
d1.resolve();

var d2 = $.Deferred();
d2.resolve();
d2.done(function() {
    console.log("I'm called synchronously");
});
```

So what's happening in your code is that the overall `done` callback that `when` fires is fired *during* the `done` callback on the last promise that got resolved (`dfd3`). Since the promise isn't marked resolved until *after* the `done` callbacks have been completed, when your code runs, `dfd1` and `dfd2` are resolved but `dfd3` is still in the process of being resolved. So your inner callbacks are called synchronously for `dfd1` and `dfd2` but *asynchronously* for `dfd3`. So you're outputting your result before the `dfd3` return value has been pushed onto your array.

Comment: Shouldn't it be fixed in jq 3.x? Because just checking using jQuery edge in jsFiddle, still getting this behaviour despite the fact [jQuery.Deferred objects have been updated for compatibility with Promises/A+ and ES2015 Promises](https://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/)

Comment: super got your explanation.

Comment: @A.Wolff: Do you still see the behavior if you use `then` instead of `done`? Note that the release notes talk about `then` (the Promises/A+ function). They may have left `done` the old way for backward compat.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ho ya, my bad, `then()` works as expected!