# Why does jQuery deferred not ensure every callback to be fired if callbacks contain errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

My attempt to properly name this question may not have met with success, therefore I will describe what is going on.

Currently I am writing extensions to a web application that is given to me. This web application uses jQuery 1.9.1. I observed the following behavior:

```
/** define callback functions */
var f1 = function () { console.log( null ); };
var f2 = function () { console.log( "oi" ); };

/** create deferred objects */
var dfd1 = $.Deferred();
var dfd2 = $.Deferred();
var dfd3 = $.Deferred();
var dfd4 = $.Deferred();

/** set behavior for .done  */
dfd1.done( f1 );
dfd1.done( f2 );

dfd2.done( f1, f2 );

dfd3.done( f2 );
dfd3.done( f1 );

dfd4.done( f2, f1 );
```

Now depending on what behavior is to be tested, uncomment either of the lines, but always only one, the other will not be processed due to an exception thrown:

```
// dfd1.resolve();
// dfd2.resolve();
// dfd3.resolve();
// dfd4.resolve();
```

I am receiving the following outputs:

1. Exception
2. Exception
3. `oi`, Exception
4. `oi`, Exception

Now. I do understand what is happening there, but do not understand the base thought behind the implementation. The line `console.log( null );` is a simple way to throw an exception. Therefore case 1 and case 2 will throw an exception and the procedure quits. In case 3 and case 4 `console.log( null );` is called **after** `f2`, as part of `f1`. So I get the console output `oi` followed by the exception.

My question is: Why is it implemented this way? Am I missing an important thought about this process? I expected both functions to be called, regardless whether one throws an exception or not, but at least in jQuery 1.9.1, I was surprised to find that this is not the case.

Doesn't it make more sense to ensure that every of the functions passed to `.done` (or `.fail`, or `...`) is actually called, no matter what happens in one of the other functions? Maybe this is merely due to an outdated jQuery version?

Please note: I am not doing any kind of chaining here. This is not supposed to be any kind of implementation of `dfd.done(...).done(...);`. What I wanted to do is to define two (or a dynamic amount) of behaviors for when a specific promise is resolved and was then surprised to figure out the behavior of one callback was able to prevent calling the other ones. My expectation was that callbacks are being handled independently, so that the other ones are called, even if one breaks down due to a mistake.

With respect to this question I looked if this was already answered, looked for similar questions in general on *StackOverflow* and looked through the documentation of `.done`. What I found was not satisfactory, if this happens to be a duplicate then apologies in advance.

Comment: This seems similar.  [Multiple Deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918740/waiting-for-multiple-deferred-objects-to-be-finished-and-use-the-resolved-values)

Comment: Hey there. No, the question you linked is with respect to multiple `$.Deferred` objects and how to proceed upon completion and rejection of multiple ones. What they mean is, you resolve multiple deferred objects and proceed *then*. Or immediately upon rejection of one. I do that too and solve this using `$.when.apply(...).then(...)`. What my question is about is processing multiple callbacks for *one* deferred object. The multiple `$.Deferred()` are merely for illustration purposes.

Comment: "*The line console.log( null ); is a simple way to throw an exception.*" - no, it doesn't throw an exception?! A "simple way" would to use `throw`.

Comment: You should use `then` anyway, not `done` or `fail`. Using `then` will also catch exceptions in the handlers and ensure that all callbacks are called. There is no such guarantee for `done` - I guess the exception simply bubbles out of the handler back to the `resolve` call.

Comment: I saw that too.  substituted with `var f1 = function () { throw 'f1 error thrown!'; };`

Comment: I tried this in my console right now to be sure, for `console.log( null );` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null`. Is this browser dependent?

Comment: But no matter, you can use any way to prevent the function from completing that is at your disposal to achieve the effect

Comment: I will look into `they`. Still wonder why this is not guaranteed for `.done`. Somehow I suspect a context issue.

Comment: @Mär Yes, `console` behaviour is browser dependent, but I've never seen a console implementation trying to `.toString()` primitive values. What browser are you using?

Comment: "*Still wonder why this is not guaranteed for `.done`.*" - I'll have to guess, but a) the jQuery authors didn't think about it b) you are not supposed to use exceptions in callback anyway

Comment: Hi, this is a native Samsung TV browser for Tizen based  b2b applications, so some unexpected behavior is to be expected. They include a jQuery version, but we include version `1.9.1` and bind it to a different variable to have certainty with respect to jQuery.

Comment: Maybe you can extend my understanding regarding exceptions @Bergi. You mentioned those are not to be used in callbacks, however the exact situation I encountered was due to unexpected values in the callback, that resulted in the error I described. The callback was then not completely executed. This question resulted from the discovery, that all further callbacks that were due upon resolve were then also ignored. I would not have expected that.

Comment: *"unexpected behavior is to be expected"*

Comment: @Mär "unexpected values" means that it's a programmer mistake. It should cause an error in the console, and it doesn't matter whether the other callbacks would run or not, the program won't work properly anyway.

Comment: Usually that is the case with the native Samsung browser, but definitely not always. There were multiple cases I observed, where no errors were passed to console and yet an error had occurred. You are absolutely right about the problem being a programmer mistake, though.